# parse github api.. getting string indices must be integers error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, github-api

I need to loop through commits and get name, date, and messages info from 
GitHub API.

https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/commits

I have many different things but I keep getting stuck at string indices must be integers error:

```
def git():
#name , date , message
#https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/commits
#commit { author { name and date
#commit { message

    #with urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project Project-Management/commits') as response:
        #source = response.read()

    #data = json.loads(source)
    #state = []
    #for state in data['committer']:
        #state.append(state['name'])
        #print(state)

    link = 'https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/events'
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/commits')
    #print(r)

    #one = r['commit']
    #print(one)
    for item in r.json():
        for c in item['commit']['committer']:
            print(c['name'],c['date'])

    return 'suc'
```

Need to get person who did the commit, date and their message.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Is an exception being thrown, or are your results just not correct? The code looks fine to me, so some extra information would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item['commit']['committer']` is a dictionary object, and therefore the line:
`for c in item['commit']['committer']:` is transiting dictionary keys.

Since you are calling `[]` on a string (the dictionary key), you are getting the error.

Instead that code should look more like:

```py
def git():
    link = 'https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/events'
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/droptable461/Project-Project-Management/commits')
    for item in r.json():
        for key in item['commit']['committer']:
            print(item['commit']['committer']['name'])
            print(item['commit']['committer']['date'])
            print(item['commit']['message'])
    return 'suc'
```